# my import os is working properly but while using playsound module I am getting an error

Tags: python-3.9

```
import os
os.startfile('D:\\python\\codewithharry\\chapter1\\song.mp3')
from playsound import playsound
playsound('D:\\python\\codewithharry\\chapter1\\song.mp3')'''
    raise PlaysoundException(exceptionMessage)
playsound.PlaysoundException:
    Error 305 for command:
        open "D:\python\codewithharry\chapter1\song.mp3"
    Cannot specify extra characters after a string enclosed in quotation marks.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you have 3 extra single quotations marks at the end of this line:

-`playsound('D:\\python\\codewithharry\\chapter1\\song.mp3')'''` which should

read:

-`playsound('D:\\python\\codewithharry\\chapter1\\song.mp3')`